# How To Have A Custom Action Located Within An Applescript.app, Execute Only On Every Fifth Launch Of The Application

Tags: applescript, backup, automation

Okay here is my situation. I have created a script whose function is to ultimately back up my script files which I save to my iCloud Drive/Script Editor folder, to two different locations. Each location is in a folder named “JIMZ_Scriptz” on two different Time Capsules.  Initially I duplicated every item located in my iCloud Drive/Script Editor folder to the “JIMZ_Scriptz” on both of my Time Capsules.  Because every file is already duplicated, the function of my script now is to only duplicate the files of my iCloud drive/ Script Editor folder, whose creation date is within the last three days and who's modification date is within the last three days to the  “JIMZ_Scriptz” on both of my Time Capsules

In my research and learning process, I’ve stumbled across … how to have an AppleScript **change the values of its already set properties based on how many times the script is run**.  For example I have this script set up that on every fifth run, it will set the value of this property… `property archiveMode : missing value` … to true.  Next I have a conditional set in this script that if archiveMode is true, then it will perform the actions I set in the conditional statement.

But here is the catch.  As long as the script does not get recompiled and resaved,  with every run of the script in Script Editor, it will continue to change the value in the `property number_of_runs : 0`  from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on.   **When compiled and saved as an application and that application is run outside of Script Editor, it loses the ability to save and store new values to properties and variables**.  Right now I have the properties set in a way that every time I launch the compiled application, it sets archiveMode to true, displaying a dialog asking me if I want to run those certain actions.

**Q: How To Have A Custom Action Located Within An Applescript.app, Execute Only On Every Fifth Launch Of The Application?**

```
property inputPath1 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:"
property inputPath2 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Script Libraries:"
property inputPath3 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Workflows:Applications:Folder Actions:"
property destinationOne : "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz"
property destinationTwo : "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz:"
property modiedDate : (current date) - (days * 3)
property creationDate : (current date) - (days * 3)
property archiveMode : missing value
property zipMe1 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property zipMe2 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Jimmy's_ATC/Jimz_Filez/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property number_of_runs : 0
property number_of_files : 0

set number_of_runs to number_of_runs + 1

if number_of_runs = 5 then
    set archiveMode to true
end if

stopTimeMachine()

set MountdestinationOne to mount volume "afp://Jimmy's AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Jimmy's_ATC"
set MountdestinationTwo to mount volume "afp://Smokestack AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Smokestack_ATC"

if archiveMode is true then
    try
        set dialogAnswer to display dialog ¬
            "Would You Like To Create An Archive Of Your JIMZ_Scriptz Folders In Both Of Your Time Capsules?" buttons {"Yes", "No", "Cancel"} ¬
            default button "Yes"
        if button returned of dialogAnswer is "Yes" then
            do shell script "zip -r " & quoted form of zipMe1 & " " & quoted form of zipMe1
            tell application "Finder"
                set moveZipFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz.zip"
                set moveZipFile to moveZipFile as alias
                set moveZipFile2 to alias "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set moveZipFileTo to alias "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set number_of_files to count (items of folder moveZipFileTo)
                set number_of_files to number_of_files + 1
                set new_zip_name to "JIMZ_Scriptz " & number_of_files & ".zip"
                set name of moveZipFile to new_zip_name
                set resultObject to move moveZipFile to moveZipFileTo without replacing
                set resultObject2 to duplicate resultObject to moveZipFile2
            end tell
            set archiveMode to false
        else
            backupScriptz()
        end if
    on error number -128 -- userCanceledErr
        stopTimeMachine()
        return
    end try
    set archiveMode to false
end if

backupScriptz()

stopTimeMachine()

on backupScriptz()
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            with timeout of 280 seconds
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
            end timeout
            with timeout of 280 seconds
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
            end timeout
        on error the error_message number the error_number
            set the error_text to "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message
            my write_error_log(the error_text)
        end try
    end tell
end backupScriptz

on write_error_log(this_error)
    set the error_log to ((path to desktop) as text) & "Jimz_Time_Capsule_Backup Error Log.txt"
    try
        open for access file the error_log with write permission
        write (this_error & " " & (current date) & return) to file the error_log starting at eof
        close access file the error_log
    on error
        try
            close access file the error_log
        end try
    end try
end write_error_log

on stopTimeMachine()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "main" of pane "com.apple.prefs.backup"
        tell application "System Events"
            perform action "AXPress" of checkbox "Back Up Automatically" of window "Time Machine" of application process "System Preferences"
        end tell
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end stopTimeMachine
```

---

**UPDATE: Here Is The Version Of The Revised Code.  This Updated Code Will Indeed Perform The Action Located Within The Conditional Clause On Every Fifth Launch Of The Application.**

The approach I took was to use the “write to file” command.  Every time the script application gets launched, it writes the word “Launched” to an external text file.  Then I used the “read file” command to count the number of the words “Launched” in the text file.  Next I copied that count to a variable and if that variable = 5 it triggers the appropriate actions and deletes the external text file, which starts the cycle back from the beginning

```
property inputPath1 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:"
property inputPath2 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Script Libraries:"
property inputPath3 : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Workflows:Applications:Folder Actions:"
property destinationOne : "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz"
property destinationTwo : "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz:"
property modiedDate : (current date) - (days * 3)
property creationDate : (current date) - (days * 3)
property archiveMode : missing value
property zipMe1 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property zipMe2 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Jimmy's_ATC/Jimz_Filez/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property number_of_files : 0
property launchCount : 0

writeToFile()

readFile()

if launchCount = 5 then
    set archiveMode to true
    tell application "Finder"
        delete alias "Macintosh HD:private:tmp:Launch_Count.txt"
    end tell
end if

stopTimeMachine()

set MountdestinationOne to mount volume "afp://Jimmy's AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Jimmy's_ATC"
set MountdestinationTwo to mount volume "afp://Smokestack AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Smokestack_ATC"

if archiveMode is true then
    try
        set dialogAnswer to display dialog ¬
            "Creating An Archive Of Your JIMZ_Scriptz Folders In Both Of Your Time Capsules?" buttons {"OK", "NO"} ¬
            default button "OK"
        if button returned of dialogAnswer is "OK" then
            do shell script "zip -r " & quoted form of zipMe1 & " " & quoted form of zipMe1
            tell application "Finder"
                set moveZipFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz.zip"
                set moveZipFile to moveZipFile as alias
                set moveZipFile2 to alias "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set moveZipFileTo to alias "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set number_of_files to count (items of folder moveZipFileTo)
                set number_of_files to number_of_files + 1
                set new_zip_name to "JIMZ_Scriptz " & number_of_files & ".zip"
                set name of moveZipFile to new_zip_name
                set resultObject to move moveZipFile to moveZipFileTo with replacing
                set resultObject2 to duplicate resultObject to moveZipFile2
            end tell
            set archiveMode to false
        else
            backupScriptz()
        end if
    end try
    set archiveMode to false
end if

backupScriptz()

stopTimeMachine()

on backupScriptz()
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            with timeout of 280 seconds
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationOne with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationOne with replacing
            end timeout
            with timeout of 280 seconds
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath1 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath2 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose modification date > modiedDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
                duplicate (every item of inputPath3 whose creation date > creationDate) to destinationTwo with replacing
            end timeout
        on error the error_message number the error_number
            set the error_text to "Error: " & the error_number & ". " & the error_message
            my write_error_log(the error_text)
        end try
    end tell
    display notification ¬
        "Your Most Recent Script Files Have Been Backed Up" with title ¬
        "BACKUP COMPLETED" sound name "Bottle"
end backupScriptz

on write_error_log(this_error)
    set the error_log to ((path to desktop) as text) & "Jimz_Time_Capsule_Backup Error Log.txt"
    try
        open for access file the error_log with write permission
        write (this_error & " " & (current date) & return) to file the error_log starting at eof
        close access file the error_log
    on error
        try
            close access file the error_log
        end try
    end try
end write_error_log

on stopTimeMachine()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        reveal anchor "main" of pane "com.apple.prefs.backup"
        try
            tell application "System Events"
                perform action "AXPress" of checkbox "Back Up Automatically" of window "Time Machine" of application process "System Preferences"
            end tell
        end try
    end tell
    tell application "System Preferences" to quit
end stopTimeMachine

on writeToFile()
    set theFile to "/tmp/Launch_Count.txt"
    set theText to "Launched"
    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    end try
end writeToFile

on readFile()
    set theFile1 to alias "Macintosh HD:private:tmp:Launch_Count.txt"
    set theCount to count words of (read theFile1)
    copy theCount to launchCount
end readFile
```

---

**UPDATE #2:** So I downloaded a scripting addition called [Satimage](http://www.satimage.fr/software/en/dictionaries/dict_satimage.html) , and reworked my code as a combination of commands from Satimage (mainly the BACKUP command) combined with some of my previous code from the UPDATE post in this topic.

Here is the latest version

**Q: Can anybody try explaining to me why this new version takes only 18 seconds to complete, without having to use timeout clauses (not including the “archive command” on the fifth launch of the application), whereas the original solution usually took the better part of 20 minutes?  How can a third party scripting addition perform 1000 times quicker than Finder.app scripting commands?**

```
property archiveMode : missing value
property zipMe1 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property zipMe2 : POSIX path of "/Volumes/Data_Jimmy's_ATC/Jimz_Filez/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz"
property number_of_files : 0
property launchCount : 0

writeToFile()

writeToFile2()

readFile()

if launchCount = 5 then
    set archiveMode to true
    tell application "Finder"
        delete alias "Macintosh HD:private:tmp:Launch_Count.txt"
    end tell
end if

if archiveMode is true then
    try
        set dialogAnswer to display dialog ¬
            "Creating An Archive Of Your JIMZ_Scriptz Folders In Both Of Your Time Capsules?" buttons {"OK", "NO"} ¬
            default button "OK"
        if button returned of dialogAnswer is "OK" then
            do shell script "zip -r " & quoted form of zipMe1 & " " & quoted form of zipMe1
            tell application "Finder"
                set moveZipFile to POSIX file "/Volumes/Data_Smokestack_ATC/JIMZ_Storage_Filez/JIMZ_Scriptz.zip"
                set moveZipFile to moveZipFile as alias
                set moveZipFile2 to alias "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set moveZipFileTo to alias "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:Zipped_Jimz_Scriptz:"
                set number_of_files to count (items of folder moveZipFileTo)
                set number_of_files to number_of_files + 1
                set new_zip_name to "JIMZ_Scriptz " & number_of_files & ".zip"
                set name of moveZipFile to new_zip_name
                set resultObject to move moveZipFile to moveZipFileTo with replacing
                set resultObject2 to duplicate resultObject to moveZipFile2
            end tell
            set archiveMode to false
        else
            backupScriptz()
        end if
    end try
    set archiveMode to false
end if

on writeToFile()
    set MountdestinationOne to mount volume "afp://Jimmy's AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Jimmy's_ATC"
    set MountdestinationTwo to mount volume "afp://Smokestack AirPort Time Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/Data_Smokestack_ATC"
    set theSource to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Mobile Documents:com~apple~ScriptEditor2:Documents:"
    set theSource2 to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Script Libraries:"
    set theSource3 to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Library:Workflows:Applications:Folder Actions:"
    set theDestination2 to alias "Data_Smokestack_ATC:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz:"
    set theDestination3 to alias "Data_Jimmy's_ATC:Jimz_Filez:JIMZ_Storage_Filez:JIMZ_Scriptz:"

    set resultText to backup theSource ¬
        onto theDestination2 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set resultText2 to backup theSource2 ¬
        onto theDestination2 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set resultText3 to backup theSource3 ¬
        onto theDestination2 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set resultText4 to backup theSource ¬
        onto theDestination3 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set resultText5 to backup theSource2 ¬
        onto theDestination3 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set resultText6 to backup theSource3 ¬
        onto theDestination3 ¬
        level 2 ¬
        after ((get current date) - 359200)

    set theFile to "/tmp/Files_To_Backup.txt"

    try
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        set theReports to write resultText & resultText2 & resultText3 & resultText4 & resultText5 & resultText6 & " " & (current date) & return to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile
        set writeToFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        set theReports to write resultText & resultText2 & resultText3 & resultText4 & resultText5 & resultText6 & " " & (current date) & return to writeToFile as text starting at eof
        close access theFile
    end try
end writeToFile

on writeToFile2()
    set theFile2 to "/tmp/Launch_Count.txt"
    set theText to "Launched"
    try
        set writeToFile2 to open for access theFile2 with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile2 as text starting at eof
        close access theFile2
    on error errMsg number errNum
        close access theFile2
        set writeToFile2 to open for access theFile2 with write permission
        write theText & linefeed to writeToFile2 as text starting at eof
        close access theFile2
    end try
end writeToFile2

on readFile()
    set theFile3 to alias "Macintosh HD:private:tmp:Launch_Count.txt"
    set theCount to count words of (read theFile3)
    copy theCount to launchCount
end readFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a counter that lives outside the script. Create a file that hold the number of runs.

You may prepend a dot to the file name to make the file invisible.

```
# https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298264/how-to-have-a-custom-action-located-within-an-applescript-app-execute-only-on-e
# perform a command every fifth time this script is run (as an app)

set file_exists to "no"
set file_name to "oa_counter"
set file_path to POSIX path of ((path to home folder)) & file_name
set run_count to 0
tell application "Finder" to if exists file_path as POSIX file then set file_exists to "yes"

if file_exists is "yes" then
    set run_count to do shell script "cat " & POSIX path of file_path # get the current run count from the file
    do shell script "rm " & POSIX path of file_path # remove the file
end if

if run_count + 1 as number is 5 then
    display dialog "5" # do this every fifth time
else
    set run_count to run_count + 1
    do shell script "cat <<EOF >> " & POSIX path of file_path & "
" & run_count # create a new file with the new run count
    return run_count
end if
```

Comment: Nicely done. What about a web service running in a container with a micro service to contain state? JK - persistence of data to a token file stored on the file system is probably the least effort solution to this unless you wanted to leverage `defaults write com.foo.whatever` to persist a counter for storage of launch counts.

Comment: @oa-  I +1 and accepted your answer.  Although I took a slightly different approach, it was your answer that set me on the right path.  Great job thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **modulo** operator:

```
set number_of_runs to number_of_runs + 1
set archiveMode to number_of_runs mod 5 = 0 -- the result is true on 5, 10, 15, etc..
```

Instead of:

```
set number_of_runs to number_of_runs + 1
if number_of_runs = 5 then
    set archiveMode to true
end if
```